# Чем заменять deprecated методы

Tags: android

Есть к примеру вот такая строка

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1)
    .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_contacts));
```

В студии это выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: чем заменять такие методы, и где можно найти актуальные методы которые могут заменить функционал deprecated-метода.

Comment: Связанный: [Табы и зачеркнутый код, что это значит и что делать?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454323/178988)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Найти актуальные методы всегда можно в документации. Конкретно по `getDrawable`: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)
`deprecated` с API 22.

Указывают, что заменить можно на `Context.getDrawable(int)` или `getDrawable(int, Theme)`, передав тему.

Либо использовать библиотеки совместимости, тогда так: `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)`, тогда не нужны проверки.

Answer (score 5):

Не забудьте добавить проверку на доступность данного метода в новом API.
Например, если новый метод есть только в API 21, то на старых версиях ОС у вас будут ошибки и нужно добавить проверку вида:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ) {
    //используем новый метод
} else {
   //используем старый deprecated метод
}
```

Comment: а если в самом методе идет проверку, мне нужно ее дублировать, или нет?    public static final Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int id) {
        final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (version >= 21) {
            return ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(context, id);
        } else {
            return context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
        }
    }

Comment: Дело в том что этот метод deprecated. Это значит, что в будущих версиях он будет исключен из SDK. Проверка внутри метода немного другое. В вашем случае нужно использовать этот метод если текущий номер API ниже 22 и новый метод, который в ответе выше если уровень API >= 22.

Comment: я не уточнил, я говорю про метод ContextCompat.getDrawable(‌​) он не deprecated, и в нем внутри происходит проверка!

Comment: да, ContextCompat можно юзать без проверок. Это класс support library.

Answer (score 3):

Идёте на Android developers в поиске вбиваете свой класс, у которого метод устарел, не забудьте предворительно указать версию API в списке пакетов, далее находите описание класса с его полями, методами и т.д., далее ищите свой метод в списке, в описании метода всегда написано, если он устарел, что лучше использовать вместо него, это касается не только методов, но и в целом любых deprecated.

На живом примере, переходите по ссылке: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dismissDialog(int)

Там в описании чётко написано, что делать.